# Gulp connect, serving some assets from a directory different from 'root'

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-connect

I wonder if it is possible with gulp-connect to serve some files from a different directory. Something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/index.html => root: '/root/app'
```

but

```
http://localhost:8008/js/main.js => from '/root/js/' not from 'root/app/js' 
http://localhost:8008/css/main.css => from '/root/css/' not from 'root/app/css/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a [middleware function](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect#optionsmiddleware) to `gulp-connect` that allows you to modify the request object and therefore rewrite request URLs:

```
gulp.task('serve', function() {
  connect.server({
    root: 'root',
    middleware: function() {
      return [ function(req, res, next) {
        if (!/^\/(js|css)\/.*/.test(req.url)) {
          req.url = '/app' + req.url;
        }
        next();
      }];
    }
  });
});
```

In the above any path that starts with `/js/` or `/css/` will be passed through unchanged. Since our base folder is `root` that means a path like `/js/main.js` will resolve to `root/js/main.js`.

All other paths will be prepended with `/app`, meaning a path like `/index.html` will transparently resolve to `root/app/index.html`.

Instead of using custom logic as I did above, you can also use something like [`http-rewrite-middleware`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-rewrite-middleware), which allows you to specify nginx-inspired rewrite expressions:

```
var rewrite = require('http-rewrite-middleware');

gulp.task('serve', function() {
  connect.server({
    root: 'root',
    middleware: function() {
      return [ rewrite.getMiddleware([
        { from: '^/js/(.*)$', to: '/js/$1' },
        { from: '^/css/(.*)$', to: '/css/$1' },
        { from: '^(.*)$', to: '/app/$1' }
      ])];
    }
  });
});
```